# Store the String of an Element Into Variable, Pass It Through Toggle()

Tags: jquery

I've started out with a div box that contains a header within it.

My hope is to have a `toggle()` event that when the header is clicked, it stores the header string into a variable, changes the HTML of that header, and animates the `parent()` div box that contains it.

The second function is to animate the `parent()` div box again, and change the HTML back to its original text (which would be stored as a variable.)

I'm having trouble though, and I'm not sure where my problem lies.  I'm using `html()` to 'get' the string of the original header, and I'm not sure that's correct.  I'm also not sure if I need more precaution to pass the variable or call the variable correctly, either.

http://jsfiddle.net/94nPv/1/

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.  Many thanks SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `.data()` method to store the original html http://jsfiddle.net/94nPv/3/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('h5').toggle(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data('originalText',$this.html());
        $this.parent('div.softwarebox').animate({ height: "700px" });
        $this.html("Close");
    }, function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.parent('div.softwarebox').animate({ height: "19px" });
        $this.html($this.data('originalText'));
    });        
});​
```

slightly optimized (no extra calls to .html or .data): http://jsfiddle.net/94nPv/7/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('h5').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data('originalText',$this.html());
    });
    $('h5').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.text() === "Close") {
            $this.html($this.data('originalText'));
            $this.parent('div.softwarebox').animate({
                height: "19px"
            });
        }
        else {
            $this.text("Close");
            $this.parent('div.softwarebox').animate({
                height: "700px"
            });
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: Awesome.  So, I guess I don't need to pass the variable through the second `toggle()` function if it's part of a greater function, so that's good to know.  Can I ask why the `var $this = $(this);`?  Just to help simplify your code later down the road?  Better practice?

Comment: It really isn't needed, I just consider it a good practice to avoid calling `$()` as much as possible. If I need to use `$(this)` more than once, I cache it in a variable instead.

Comment: So with something like this http://jsfiddle.net/94nPv/8/, is there even a need to declare a variable?  I guess `data()` kind of does that already by naming the set?

Comment: `var headertext = ` can be removed since it is never used. The rest of that line is needed though.